# Create AsyncTask on a separate class and trying to return value from it using interface . Java.lang.ClassCastException cannot be cast

Tags: android

Create AsyncTask on a separate class and trying to return value from it using interface `Java.lang.ClassCastException` cannot be cast. If I did the same thing using activity everything works fine but using Adapter I'm not been able to make it work I  dont know the reason behind it. Can someone please suggest.

```
            /* Separate Java class extends AsyncTask*/
             public class Task extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> 
             {
              /* Declaraing required variables */
              Context context;
              TaskCompleted taskCompleted;
              public Task(Context context){
              this.context = context;

              /* The problem is right in this line */          
              /* Java.lang.ClassCastException cannot be cast.*/
              this.taskCompleted = (TaskCompleted) context; 
            }
            @Override
             protected void onPreExecute() {
               super.onPreExecute();
             }

             @Override
             protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
             //Return string value
             return "hello";
            }
              @Override
              protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
              super.onPostExecute(s);
              //add string value
              taskCompleted.output(s);
             }
           }
           /*Interface class to store asynctask value */
           public interface TaskCompleted {
          /* Method to get value set from asynctask */
           public void output(String value);
           }
           /*If i did the same thing using activity 
             everything works fine but using Adapter i m not been able 
             to make it work i  dont know the reason behind it. Can 
             someone please suggest.*/

           /* Adapter Class implements Interface Class */               
           public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter implements   
           TaskCompleted {
          /* Declaring the variable */
          private Context context;
          private List<String> list;
          private LayoutInflater inflater;

        /* Create Constructor to send required value */
        public Adapter(Context context, List<String> list) {
         /* Setting up value */
         this.context = context;
         this.list = list;
         inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
        }

        @Override
         public int getCount() {
          /* Size of ArrayList */
         return list.size();
       }

       @Override
       public String getItem(int position) {
        /* return value of particular position */
        return list.get(position);
      }

      @Override
      public long getItemId(int position) {
         return 0;
      }
      /*Get View from here for just to test*/
      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup 
      parent) {
       /* Call class to get views */
       MyViewHolder mViewHolder;

        //get custom layout
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,  
         parent, false);
            //initialize view holder class
            mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
        } else {
            mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        mViewHolder.nameTextView.setText(list.get(position));

        //add listener
        mViewHolder.nameTextView.setOnClickListener(new 

        View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Call AsyncTask class to execute 
                new Task(context).execute();
                }
             }); 
             return convertView;
           }

          @Override
            public void output(String value) {
         /*Printing value*/
         Toast.makeText(context,value+" From 
            Interface",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }

            private class MyViewHolder {
                TextView nameTextView;

                public MyViewHolder(View item) {
               /* Get view from layout */
               nameTextView = (TextView)    
               item.findViewById(R.id.nameId);
               }
              }
             }
```

Comment: Yes i have posted code..

Comment: try sending the context from activity to the adapter and then from adapter to the asynctask

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
new Task(context).execute();
```

To:

```
new Task(Adapter.this).execute();
```

Adapter is the implementation of the interface, not context.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the async task from adapter use the following flow.
Since you are calling from adapter you have to pass the instance of the Activity ,so the result from async task goes to the interface on the activity. Call your adapter method from there.

```
Adapter{   
Activity mActivity;
 Adapter(Activity activity){
 mActivity = activity;
 yourAsyncTask async = new AsyncTask(activity);
 async.execute(url);
}
public void asyncTaskResult(){
 //Do what you want to do here.
}

}


Your AsyncTask{
Activity mActivity;
AysncTask(Activity activity){
mActivity = activity;
}

onPostExecute(){
((YourInterface)mActivity).resultMethod();

 }

} 

Interface YourInterface(){
public void resultMethod();

}

Your Activity Implements YourInterface{

@Override
public void resultMethod(){
yourAdapter.asyncTaskResult();

}   

}
```